# If array value is repeated in another array, combine both arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have several arrays that I want to check for a repeated value and if the value is found to be repeated in one of the other arrays, then combine both of those arrays together.

I give an example below of 2 arrays that have repeated values.

**example:** the value in `purchase_order_number` is the same in both arrays below. They are not unique values. But the values in `tracking_number` are unique.

I want to check if the value in `purchase_order_number` is repeated in another array. If the same value is found in another array, then combine both of those arrays into 1 array.

I'm trying to get the value in `tracking_number` and `service` combined into a single array when the value in `purchase_order_number` is the same in 2 or more arrays.

Example arrays below.

**not combined**

```
    array (
      'data' => 
      array (
        15 => 
        array (
          'type' => 'Tracking',
          'id' => 2830143,
          'attributes' => 
          array (
            'tracking_number' => '1Z5270560360309870',
            'service' => 'UPS',
            'order_id' => 2606218,
            'purchase_order_number' => '7249491',
            'recipient_attempts' => 1,
          ),
        ),
        16 => 
        array (
          'type' => 'Tracking',
          'id' => 2830144,
          'attributes' => 
          array (
            'tracking_number' => '1Z5270560361740866',
            'service' => 'UPS',
            'order_id' => 2606218,
            'purchase_order_number' => '7249491',
            'recipient_attempts' => 1,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Example given below of how I need to combine the two above arrays.

**Combined**

```
    array (
      'data' => 
      array (
        16 => 
        array (
          'type' => 'Tracking',
          'id' => 2830144,
          'attributes' => 
          array (
            'tracking' => 
            array (
              0 => 
              array (
                'tracking_number' => '1Z5270560360309870',
                'service' => 'UPS',
              ),
              1 => 
              array (
                'tracking_number' => '1Z5270560361740866',
                'service' => 'UPS',
              ),
            ),
            'order_id' => 2606218,
            'purchase_order_number' => '7249491',
            'recipient_attempts' => 1,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: not searching for answer on this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a *reduce* based solution with caveats:

```
$arr['data'] = array_reduce($arr['data'], function ($out, $item) {
    // keys we want to extract
    static $tracking_keys = ['tracking_number' => '', 'service' => ''];
    // yank tracking keys from attributes
    $tracking = array_intersect_key($item['attributes'], $tracking_keys);
    $item['attributes'] = array_diff_key($item['attributes'], $tracking_keys);
    // insert to new array based on order number
    $order_no = $item['attributes']['purchase_order_number'];
    if (!isset($out[$order_no])) {
        $item['attributes']['tracking'] = [$tracking];
        $out[$order_no] = $item;
    } else {
        array_push($out[$order_no]['attributes']['tracking'], $tracking);
    }
    return $out;
}, []);
```

Keys in `'data'` are not retained and `'id'` is set by the first item.